# Error while trying in Angular ng new --collection

Tags: angular, typescript, module, compiler-errors, infragistics

I'm deploying an angular app and using Infragistics. I've installed via npm install Infragistics, like on their Documentation.
While running

`ng new --collection="@igniteui/angular-schematics"`

I am getting this error:

> The new command requires to be run outside of a project, but a project
> definition was found at
> │my/path/toAngularProject/angular.json".

I'm also not able to import f.e. `IxGridModule` in `app.module.ts`.

Is there a connection? Can someone help me? :/

Answer (score 4):

The `ng new` command creates a new, blank application. I think you already have an application and try to run that command in the existing application folder, hence you see the error that a project definition is already present. The CLI pretty much warns you that you try to create an application in an application - which is obviously nonesense.

If you want to add the library to an existing application, you need to use the `ng add` command for that library, in your case `ng add igniteui-angular` as stated [in the documentation](https://www.infragistics.com/products/ignite-ui-angular/angular/components/general/getting-started#quick-start-with-the-angular-cli).

Comment: Oh thanks, that worked. But when i want to import some modules of igniteui-angular in app.module.ts it throws a lot of errors saying stuff like :  

  node_modules/@angular/core/core"' has no exported member 'ɵɵInjectorDeclaration'.

Comment: Got the problem. I'm working with Angular 11 and ignite-angular was Version 13. I installed an older Version and now it's working. Thanks for help.